# SSIS SharePoint List Source - MessageSecurityException HTTP request not authorized 401 on single site

Tags: web-services, kerberos, ntlm

Got a connecting issue just on a singe site collection running in **SharePoint 2013**...

Using the SSIS "SharePoint List Source" or "SharePoint List Destination" there is an issue with a single sitecollection connecting - **(401) not authorized**.

The web application is (as every web application in our farm) set to **kerberos(negotiate)**. The user used in credentials is **farm admin, primary site collection administrator and member of the "Sitename Owners" group**. So there should not be any permission issue. He can enter the site by browser without any problems.

Trying to connect by SSIS to one of the sites lists the following error occures:

```
MessageSecurityException HTTP-Anforderung "Ntlm" nicht autorisiert "Negotiate,NTLM" empfangen. ---> System.Net.WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---

Server stack trace: 
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoap.GetListAndView(GetListAndViewRequest request)
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoapClient.ListsService_ListsSoap_GetListAndView(GetListAndViewRequest request)
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoapClient.GetListAndView(String listName, String viewName)
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.Adapter.ListsAdapter.GetSharePointFields(String listName, String viewId)
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListServiceUtility.GetFields(Uri sharepointUri, NetworkCredential credentials, String listName, String viewName)
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListDestination.GetAccessibleSharePointColumns(String sharepointUrl, String listName, String viewName)
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListDestination.ValidateSharePointColumns()
   bei Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListDestination.Validate()
   bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostValidate(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
```

But this just occures at this site. Can the fact this site being in another content database be the issue? The database permissions seem to be ok.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, that this error occures when the user running visual studio has no permission to enter the SharePoint site on which the content to be read/written is stored. **Visual Studio does not use the stored credential when hitting the "Start" button to check dtsx package functionality.** Be aware of this behavior!